# Passing by const copy

Tags: c++

Is there any benefit (or conversely, cost) to passing a parameter by const value in the function signature?

So:

```
void foo( size_t nValue )
{
    // ...
```

vs

```
void foo( const size_t nValue )
{
    // ...
```

The only reason for doing this that I can think of would be to ensure the parameter wasn't modified as part of the function although since it has not been passed by reference there would be no wider impact outside the function.

Comment: You have answered your question by yourself.

Comment: I thought so, but I wanted to ask in case there was something I was missing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course there is. You can't modify `nValue` inside the function.

As with `const`-ness in general, it's not a security measure, since you can cast it away, but a design matter.

You're explicitly telling other programmers that see your code -

> "I will not modify `nValue` inside this function

and programmers that maintain or change your code

> "If you want to modify `nValue`, you're probably doing something wrong. You shouldn't need to do this".

Comment: I agree more with this answer than others due to the fact Luchian mentions enforcing designs. Passing parameters as const will help ensure no modifications occur to the value. You can always hack past this as he mentioned, but the base principle is ensuring data is managed properly.

Answer (score 5):

The top-level `const` here affects only the definition of the function and only prevents you from modifying the value of `nValue` in the function.

The top-level `const` does not affect the function declaration.  The following two declarations are exactly the same:

```
void foo(size_t nValue);
void foo(const size_t nValue);
```

Comment: Agreed, I've seen code like this and trying to work out if I'd missed something here.

Comment: They may be 'exactly' the same in the sense that removing `const` does not alter the resulting binary code, but adding `const` certainly adds restrictions on what the function implementation can do with the passed value. This statement is like saying that `class` and `struct` are exactly the same -- on some level that's true, but...

Comment: @GeorgeSkoptsov:  No, they are exactly the same.  The `const` does not affect the function _declaration_ at all.  It only affects the _definition_ of the function.  If you put both of these declarations into a C++ program, they both declare the same function.

Comment: @GeorgeSkoptsov: 8.3.5p5 *[...] After producing the list of parameter types, any top-level cv-qualifiers modifying a parameter type are deleted when forming the function type.* That is, the `const` in the code above is removed from the function type.

Answer (score 0):

Using const you also ensure that you're not incorrectly trying to alter the value of the parameter inside the function, regardless if the parameter is modifiable or not.

Answer (score 0):

if you define the input parameter const, you can just call const functions on that object.

anyway if you try to change that object accidentally, you will get a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently decided to do this. I like doing it as a sort of consistency with `const &` and `const *` parameters. const correctness makes life better, so why not go all in for it? If you know you're not going to change the value, why not make it const? Making it const communicates that intention clearly.